# Please help me additional allowfullscreen into this code

Tags: javascript, youtube, lazy-loading

I have a lazyload script to load iframe youtube video.
But the script does not set up the video does not open fullscreen allowfullscreen be.
So thanks to everyone helping me edit this code.
Sorry for my english is somewhat less.

```
codepen.io/caingot/pen/pgyQrp
```

Comment: [What is the core purpose of this code?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my english is quite bad so I do not understand the rules on the presentation and use of the website too, I was a foreigner. I just have one small question would, and hope to receive help from you
Hopefully I did not make a mistake about the provisions of website